# Is there a way to send a file using POST from a Python script, with specific name, that I can catch from api?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests

I want to use the `requests` package to make a post request, passing on a file with a specific name.

I already tried following, but it says "no file by name resume found":

```
with open('resume.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(url, files={'resume.pdf': f})
```

Below is the way I am trying to fetch file named `resume` in my API:

```
resume = request.files.get('resume')
```

Using the post request in postman with form-data as 'resume', type as file in dropdown, and then selecting file works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Try `resume = request.files.get('resume.pdf')`. File name includes extension.

Such view echoes file contents:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/file', methods=['POST'])
def file_endpoint():
    resume = request.files.get('resume.pdf')
    return resume.read()
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way too.
The key for my form-data is 'resume' , I don't understand how it makes a difference.